# Looking for a Sci fi harry potter fanfiction

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I am looking for a Sci fi *Harry Potter* fanfiction. Harry is in a future timeline. He has house elves working for him in his spaceship. The magical people are all extinct and corporations control the universe. He has one of his eyes stolen to take part of his magic. He also ends up enslaving a few girls.

Lastly, I remember the story was still WIP and I think it had the word "star" in its title.

The Harry in this story is centuries old, but he is unable to age as he is immortal. He was sealed by the Ministry of Magic after he dealt with Voldemort. As far as I can recall he was encased in a rock and was floating in space. He woke up centuries later in a future timeline where there are no more wizards or witches.

The fanfiction was written in English and I think I read this some 3-4 years back. I also think the author might have removed it from the fanfiction site at one time.

I had read this on fanfiction.net

Comment: This is a bit terse, but is a decent start. I recommend visiting https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question and https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fan-fiction-story-id-question ti elicit more details that will help us to find your stories. You can [edit] in the new details as you realize them. How did Harry wind up in the future? Time travel? Just lived that long? Was he still a teenager? I assume this is a spaceship, not a water-bound one?

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question and added more info it.

Comment: That may indeed help. Do you remember which site you used to read stories on? Side note, you may get some downvotes because this is a fanfic question. The system lets people vote their opinion, and there are always a few who dislike this sort of question. Please don't feel discouraged as it's usually a small dip in the score.

Comment: 'WIP'?  Work in progress?

Comment: yes WIP is work in progress

Comment: @FuzzyBoots thanks for the support, I was googling around and saw a similar question, assumed I could also post mine. Didn't know ppl had a vendetta against fanfics

Comment: @RickRoy - They're on-topic, it's just that some people aren't keen on them. They tend to come down harder on weird porny slashfic than just normal fanfic.

Comment: :) If you look for `[story-identification] [fan-fiction]` on this site, you'll see I've posted a few of my own.

Comment: Do you remember if this was a crossover with a movie/show/book? Because it sounds like something that could be a crossover with Firefly, Star Wars, Star Trek, Dune, etc. If it is, that might help us narrow it down some more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to find the story.

Title: [The Star Empire](https://forums.darklordpotter.net/threads/the-star-empire-by-rahxephon-m-nc-17.18834/)
Author: RahXephon

> A reviled Harry Potter was imprisoned and exiled into space. Many centuries later, he wakes up to a solar system devoid of magic, but infested with crime, piracy and corruption. He adjusts to this violent era like a fish to water. Dark!Harry, AU, OCs.

The author has removed the work from most spots on the web due to the difficulty of finding a place to host adult content.

Comment: https://www.scribd.com/document/460759518/The-Star-Empire-the-Succession-of-Magic-RahXephon-Harry-Potter-09042013-65 does provide a copy of it.

Comment: Thank you for coming back to provide the answer and accept.